# Changing a flat image's color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have a flat white circular image (as in a seriously flat `#ffffff` image). Is there a way I can change it's color in the context of an HTML page (let's assume `PNG`, so we're working with an RGBA raster)?

My environment uses jQuery, so I'm inclined to think within the jQuery mindset, but if something else makes this possible, I'd like to hear about it as well.

I'm not well versed with the capabilities of Canvas so much, but maybe that can do something like this. With respect to browser support however, I'd really appreciate it if the solution can touch base with IE6 (yeah, I know it's dead, but bear with me on this one).

Comment: you can make the png image transparent on the area you want color to change and wrap it in a div. Then change the divs background color. So you gotta do a negative mask. The only problem is that you can only have one color - or gradient with css3

Comment: that would work with rectangular images, but with circular images, the areas outside the circle but within the bounding box will be iffy to deal with. especially if these particular images overlap somehow.

Comment: er - yea overlapping will cause a problem. You could use css sprites instead then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up utilizing canvas after all. Scrapping the image idea, and just going with drawing the circles using canvas (and [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas) to make it modular with the jQuery environ). Basically going with treating the `<canvas>` tag itself as the `<img>` equivalent, and maybe work with dynamically creating them as needed.

To get it working with pre-IE9 browsers (where HTML5 support is non-existent), there's a nifty lib out there called [ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) which brings the canvas functionality to pre-IE9 browsers (it certainly works with the IE7 quirks mode on IE9 at least).

There's expectedly a performance drop if you're going to be performing canvas animations on ExplorerCanvas, but since this is all just 2D static, it shouldn't be too much of a problem.

There's also the matter of [dealing with dynamic `<canvas>` elements with ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions#Dynamically_created_elements), but that should be easily remedied.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a canvas and drawing the circle below the image, then change it's color? Following on from the other answer and make the image transparent and then layer it about the canvas.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/

Comment: As said in my question, yeah, I have been looking into canvas, but am just a bit wary of the browser support repercussions. I'll look into this anyway though.

Comment: Yep, let us know how it goes. Surprising how easy it is to work with canvas. Unfortunately browser wars mean it's not always that simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can 'emulate' a circle in browsers that support border radius. Try;

```
<div class="circle"/>

.circle{
    background:blue;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Then change background-color accordingly.

Yeah, I know, no IE6 support but maybe you could fall back on the transparent image effect as mentioned above

Comment: Yeah, was looking into `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius` as well. Thanks for bringing that up.